# How do I find companies that would build prototypes for me?

Tags: arduino

Im asking since I have projects that I would like to test, but honestly have little to no time to do this myself. Particularly since I've never even welded since I was a kid.

I just need to know how to finds these people and/or companies? Are there magazines? Web searches? I've come up empty or with links that are not relevant.

Projects could include arduino or RasPi.

Comment: Did you design the product and you just need somebody to manufacture it for you. Or do you need someone to turn an idea into a detailed design?

Comment: You want a small electronics assembler; it won't be particularly cheap for 1-offs or small production runs.

Comment: The best place to look is among your extended contacts (friends of friends).  Finding a right shop is not easy.  It may take time.  It's easier to find the right shop, if you take a stab at your project yourself first.

Comment: P.S.  I think, this question might work in the meta better.  Previously, the questions like this worked in the meta fairly well.

Comment: google PCB design. Do you have a schematic or just an idea? Be prepared to pay a bit, electronics design takes a lot longer than many people think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem **you want someone to make some project for you**

- Look for your local electronics market, There are many people doing these kind of jobs
- Asks your friends or friend's friend for a reputed firm or individual
- If you find no one there (which is extreme case) then go to online and look for freelancing and choose people according to their repute, reviews and budget that suits you well.